# I want to assign a variable to a input separated by comma in bash

Tags: bash

Here is my code

```
echo "Tell me your variables separated by comma: "

# EJ: Johnny, Paul, Mary

read variables

#I want to assing a variable to each name
#like:
#name1=Johnny
#name2=Paul
#name3=Mary

#but i want it to do it automatically
```

I just want to assing a variable to each name the user gives to the input.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a fixed number of values expected, you can simply use

```
 IFS=, read -r name1 name2 name3
```

If the number of values is arbitrary, read into an array instead:

```
 IFS=, read -ra names
```

Then you can access all the names at once with `"${names[@]}"`, or pick out individual names with `"${names[0]}"`, `"${names[1]}"`, etc. To find out how many names you have, use `"${#names[@]}"`.

Comment: and inspect the array with `declare -p names`